# Node.js Request timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, sip

I'm using Node.js to write a sip server. When a call is made to the sip server it works as expected. That is, it gets the caller's number and posts it to a PHP script using a Node module called Request. However, after a number of minutes the connection timeouts. I've tried setting the timeout option within Request to a large number but it keeps timing out after a couple of minutes. Is there a way to keep the connection open ?

The code below is the post request to the php script. This is executed every time a call is made to the sip server.

```
       request.post({
            uri: 'http://mj.example.com/api.php',
            timeout: 800000, 
            form: {
                apiKey:"ba6fdfsdf4fc3-0fdfsa52-90dfe3-a51dsfad-fefdfdsdfasdasdf1e7",
                action:"incomingCall",
                number :incoming_number} 
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    util.log(body)
                }else{
                  util.log("Error");
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Is the request to your PHP script ever successful from the Node server?

Comment: Still haven't figured this out. At the moment we've a hack which simply re-registers the sip client before it timeouts. This obviously isn't ideal. I'll post a solution if and when we get it sorted.